# changes-package: can highlighted text wrap into the next line?

Tags: highlighting, wrap, changes

In using the `\highlight` command in the changes-package on text that spans multiple lines, the text runs off the page rather than wrapping into the next line, as shown in the MWE. Is there a way around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\bigskip

\highlight{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: changes uses a colorbox, this doesn't allow a line break see also https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/issues/91  (but the suggested workaround to redefine \colorbox is probably not a very good idea).

Comment: Agreed --- using package ulem seems preferable than the suggested workaround!